# A tool that converts PNG8 back to PNG32

Tags: png, image-conversion

I have an image in PNG8 format with alpha transparency and want to edit it. In order to open it in GIMP without loosing quality I would need to convert it to PNG32. Anyone knows tool that does this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I believe I made a rather clear description about what I want to achieve. Do you have any suggestion about how to improve it?

Comment: Are you sure opening an 8-bit image in GIMP makes it *loose quality*? Even if GIMP internally converts it to 32-bit, that won't loose a thing. The other way around *would* be an issue, though.

Comment: It seems that png8 and png32 save alpha transparency in an very different way. Areas that are transparent in png8 turn black when you open it in GIMP (or PSD). Also the image becomes completely pixelated. I guess they kind of must use different algorithms for compression...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Adobe Fireworks does the trick.

And here is more info: https://superuser.com/questions/265697/convert-compressed-png-8-back-to-png-24

Answer (score 0):

With LEADTools you can convert png 8 to png 32, I don't know exactly how it works, but I think you can find information of the program.

You can download it free [here](http://www.leadtools.com/downloads/free-utilities.htm)

Comment: The conversion turns the alpha transparent pixels plain black... so that isn't really usefull

Comment: I'm from LEADTOOLS support and want to elaborate about the comment added by evami. 
The free utility in the link doesn't have all the PNG features supported by our toolkit. 
Our SDK handles 3 types of 8-bit PNG transparency: alpha for each pixel, alpha for each palette color and single transparent color.
 
For the simple case of converting 8-bit with alpha to 32-bit, you do that by simply loading the 8-bit image but forcing the load function to use 32-bit instead of the default.

If anybody needs more details, please email support@leadtools.com and specify the programming language you're using